# For which values of $y$ and $z$ is $\cos\left(2y+z\right)>0$

Tags: trigonometry, convex-optimization, positive-definite, hessian-matrix

Let U be the following set
$$U=\{\left(x, y, z\right)\in\mathbb R^3 \ | \ x^2+y^2+z^2<\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2\} $$
we define the function $f : U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as
$$f\left(x, y, z\right)=x^2+y^2-\cos\left(2y+z\right)$$

Is $f$ strictly convex?

The way I want to show it, is by showing the following
$$v^t Av>0$$
for every $v\in\mathbb R^n \backslash \{0\}$
where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. If the above hold, the matrix $A$ is positive definite and we then have a theorem that says that $f$ is strictly convex.

I set A to be the Hessian matrix, so we get the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \end{pmatrix}^t
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2+4\cos\left(2y+z\right) & 2\cos\left(2y+z\right) \\
0 & 2\cos\left(2y+z\right) & \cos\left(2y+z\right) \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \end{pmatrix}$$
$$=2x^2+4y^2\cos\left(2y+z\right)+2y^2+4yz\cos\left(2y+z\right)+z^2\cos\left(2y+z\right)$$
$$=2x^2+2y^2+\cos\left(2y+z\right)\left(4y^2+4yz+z^2\right)$$
$$=2x^2+2y^2+\cos\left(2y+z\right)\left(2y+z\right)^2$$
it is clear to see that $2x^2, 2y^2, \left(2y+z\right)^2>0$ for any value of $x, y, z$. I know that for any value $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$, then $\cos\left(x\right)>0$. Im struggling to find out whether $\cos(2y+z)$ is positve or negative when we have the set $U$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $|x|,|y|,|z|\lt\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: but how can I show that $\cos\left(2y+z\right)>0$

Comment: It follows from $-\frac{\pi}{6}\lt y,z\lt\frac{\pi}{6}$ that $-\frac{\pi}{2}\lt 2y+z\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: It make sense now, thank you